# Get the repeater selected item on pageinit

Tags: asp.net, repeater

I have a page with a menu like navigation pane (too repeater) and a placeholder in these page.

This is my problem : on menu item click i open different control in my placeholder, one at click.
When i change them selected item in my menu on page init i load the old control and i load  the new control on menu event. How i can get te selected item of a repeater on page initor load the,  items are LinkButton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have add no linkbutton but html link and the postback with _doPostback, i can catch the the value of the eventargrt